# Symfony 2.8 - FormBuilder : why field becomes required when I define its type?

Tags: symfony, required, formbuilder

I'm building a form like with two non mandatory fileds :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact);
$form->add('name');
$form->add('subject', TextType::class);
$form->getForm();
```

After rendering the first field is not required (it's normal) but why the second is ?! What's wrong with this code ?

Thanks :)

Comment: How did you understood that first is not required?

Comment: When I look into the html code of the page (http) I can see the required attribute in the seconde input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

required default value is defined in type class method `configureOptions()`

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'required' => true,
    ));
}
```

and in all parents for this type (parent is defined by `getParent()` method)
first parent is `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType` and there required default value is defined as true, to it is strange that first input is not required.

you can define required while adding new element `$form->add('subject', TextType::class, array('required' => false));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be the related entity to this form. Are name and subject nullable?. If no ORM configured then you need to manually set the required attribute to each form field. Look the example of a contact form without ORM.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('fullName', null, array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Name',
                        'class' => 'text gradient'

                )))
                ->add('email','email', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Email',
                        'class' => 'text gradient'
                )))
                ->add('subject', null, array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Subject',
                        'class' => 'text gradient'
                )))
                ->add('body', 'textarea', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Message',
                        'class' => 'text gradient'
            )));
    }
```

Comment: Here is my code : 
`namespace Blog\FrontBundle\Entity;

class Contact
{
    private $name;
    private $subject;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setSubject($subject){
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function getSubject(){
        return $this->subject;
    }
}`

Comment: OK, and where is the mapping information related to that entity, http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information, that's where the nullable information is defined .

Comment: I'm not using any ORM, just a controller building simple form ! I have a simple Entity representing the object, a controller to build a form using the entity and a view to display the form : no database !

Comment: I see, then you need to manually set the required attribute for each form field, I'm going to edit my post to show you a contact form related to an entity exactly like yours.

Comment: thanks for you explanations, but I think my question was not clear : I d'ont want any required fields. Why the field becomes required when I specify its type ? I mean why `$form->add('name')` generate NON required field but `$form->add('name', TextType::class)` generate a required one ?

Comment: @Max P. gave the answer : in Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType.php , line 210 : `required' => true,` , if we change it with false then all fileds are not required anymore